# SSIS 2014 Package Execution through a proxy fails

Tags: ssis

I'm trying to run an SSIS package with a SQL Server Job. I want to find a way to run the package without assigning a user with sysadmin role to the job owner. I've created a credential and proxy to run the job step, but I get a stream of errors. I can get the package to run by setting a sysadmin user to the job owner and setting the job step to run under the sql server agent service account. When I try to run as the proxy I get errors, even when I've set the credential of the proxy to a sysadmin user. I tried what the error suggests and opened all the script tasks in the package. They all build successfully. Does anyone know what I have to do to get the proxy account to run this package successfully?

```
Error: 2015-10-08 09:35:53.46
   Code: 0x00000005
   Source: Script Task Script Task
   Description: Failed to compiled scripts contained in the package. Open the package in SSIS Designer and resolve the compilation errors.
End Error
Error: 2015-10-08 09:35:53.46
   Code: 0x00000005
   Source: Script Task Script Task
   Description: Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))
End Error
Error: 2015-10-08 09:35:53.48
   Code: 0x00000005
   Source: Script Task Script Task
   Description: The binary code for the script is not found. Please open the script in the designer by clicking Edit Script button and make sure it builds successfully.
End Error
```

Comment: Interesting... Is this using the Project Deployment Model or the classic Package Deployment Model? If you have a package that does not use a Script Task, does it work?

Comment: It's deployed to the file system through an nsis installer. I did try once creating a deployment with the build that created an SSISDeploymentManifest file. But the same thing happens.

Comment: I just tested creating a simple package with just a sql statement in it. that runs fine in the sql job with the proxy.

Comment: There's no chance that these packages are in an earlier version 2005/2008/2012 and it's also upgrading them as part of the execution, is it?

Comment: Is this package running fine in SSDT locally?

Comment: It looks like that was the problem. Thanks billinkc. If I upgrade the packages, they run under the proxy user.

Answer (score 0):

I had to upgrade the packages to 2014. After that they ran successfully under the proxy.